# Regex expression with Validators.pattern for just integer number

Tags: regex, angular, formbuilder, angular-custom-validators

I am trying to create a validator for only integers (e.g., 60) using Regex. 
Here how I am trying to do it:

```
meter: ["", Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/)]
```

It does not work, but I have to say I am not familiar with this technique. 
Anyone could shed some light on how I could modify this expression to accept just integers? 
This number is for height, and the height is devided into meters and centimeter.

I have searched, but I could find for decimals and so, somehow, maybe because it is too trivial, for just integers, I cannot find, in fact, I have found yesterday here, but I cannot find the answer anymore I have found, I was looking for another thing.

Comment: I don't have anything to test right now. How about `Validators.pattern(/^-?[0-9]+$/)`

Comment: Thanks. It works partially, except for negative, it allows negative numbers.

Comment: Found: `^[-+]?\d*$`. Adapted from: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=negative&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: You never told that negative is not allowed. Just remove `-?` for positive numbers only.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it is time to eat! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a custom validator to do this, as regular expression validation is already a built-in validator.

Secondly, the way you apply validators to your form controls depending on either you are using [template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

If you are using template-driven forms (which is commonly used for Angular beginners), simply make your input control template look like this:

```
<input type="number" name="meter" required pattern="[0-9]" [(ngModel)]="meter">
```

If you are using reactive forms, just assign both "required" and "pattern" validator to your form control.

```
<input type="number" [formControl]="myControl">
```

```
myControl = new FormControl(null, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")
  ]);
```

When using it in a reactive form control, you can pass in either a string or a regex object, there are differences between them as stated in official docs:

> If a string is passed, the ^ character is prepended and the $ character is appended to the provided string (if not already present), and the resulting regular expression is used to test the values.

Lastly, a Stackblitz example attached to show simple usage of this validator in both template/reactive forms.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-neux3n